# Why doesn't my 'if' statement exit the do-while loop and if my 'catch' statement is executed, why doesn't it take input?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, try-catch, do-while

**Question 1:** If an `int` greater or equal to `2` is entered by the user the first `if` statement becomes `true` and the code is executed setting the `boolean` `error1` variable to false. The `do` loop should only repeat if the `error1` variable is `true` according to my `while` statement. However the loop repeats regardless.

How can I make the first `if` statement when set to `true` exit the loop?

**Question 2:** I am using a `try-catch` code to help repeat the the `do-while` loop if anything other than an `int` is entered by the user. However, when something like `abc` or `12.3` is entered the first `println` of the `try` code is executed, the second line of the `try` statement asking for user input is ignored and the `catch` code is executed again. This becomes a non-terminating loop without user input.

How can I get the statement to ask for user input after the `catch` code is executed?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeepbotCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int points = 0;
    boolean error1 = false;

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("How many points do you currently have?");
            points = input.nextInt();

            if (points >= 2){
                error1 = false;
            }

            else if (points > 0 && points < 2) {
                System.out.println("you need at least 2 points");
                error1 = true;
            }

            else if (points <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive whole number");
                error1 = true;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive whole number.");
            error1 = true;
        }
    } while (error1 = true);
```

Comment: Why did you edit your question with the solution?

Comment: Dido what @SotiriosDelimanolis said. How will future readers make sense of the answer/solution.

Comment: Never edit your question overriding the original code with your solution.
If you want to add the solution, you can do it at the end as an update to the question.
And remember to always format everything that is part of your code, not using apostrophes.

Comment: I added the solution to my question so future readers won't answer the same part of the question multiple times. In the future I won't do this. I'll also use proper formatting when talking about my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeepbotCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input;

        int points = 0;
        boolean error1 = false;

        do {

            try {
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("How many points do you currently have?");
                points = input.nextInt();


                if (points >= 2) {
                    error1 = false;
                }

                else if (points > 0 && points < 2) {
                    System.out.println("you need at least 2 points");
                    error1 = true;
                }

                else if (points <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a positive whole number");
                    error1 = true;
                }

            }

            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive whole number.");
                error1 = true;
            }

        } while (error1);
    }
}
```

I changed `while(error1 = true)` by `while(error1)`, and added a new line of code in the `try{}` statement.

Each time the `try{}` statement is executed, a new `Scanner` object is created overriding the last one.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the loop when the correct input is inserted,

```
while (error1 = true);
```

should become

```
while (error1 == true);
```

or even better

```
while(error1);
```

To fix the endless loop when the incorrect input is inserted, inside the `catch` add

```
input.nextLine();
```

to let the scanner "move on"

Comment: Thanks I was unaware that just putting a Boolean variable in at statement would test it but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: The endless loop without user input still occurs when the catch statement is executed though.

Comment: Edited for the endless loop

Comment: That repeated the loop while asking for user input each time until a valid input. Thank you. This answered my question.